# Remove acount user name and Password filed for particular category on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

Hope every One Doing well.
I am trying to remove account password and account user field from checkout page.
This code is working perfect.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['account']['account_password']);
     unset($fields['account']['account_password-2']);
     unset($fields['account']['account_username']);
     return $fields;
}
```

But Problem Is that ,I have only remove this for some category.
so I am trying to remove by category.
so My code is some think like that but its not work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     global $product;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat = $term->slug;
    } 
    if ($product_cat='age-defying-skincare') {
    unset($fields['account']['account_password']);
     unset($fields['account']['account_password-2']);
     unset($fields['account']['account_username']);
     return $fields;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an action hook. It can not update the or remove the field.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated );
```

If you want to make changes in user field.

**woocommerce_new_customer_data** this is a filter hook.

Then try this hook:

```
      $new_customer_data = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', array( 
          'user_login' => $username,  
          'user_pass' => $password,  
          'user_email' => $email,  
          'role' => 'customer',  
 ) );
```

You will get more detail about this here.
http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/files/includes-wc-user-functions/

Updated:
**For WooCommerc Checkout Fields**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    // Categories Array
    $categories = array('age-defying-skincare');

    foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item ){
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            unset($fields['account']['account_password']);
            unset($fields['account']['account_password-2']);
            unset($fields['account']['account_username']); 
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Try above code.

Comment: Shrikant Yadav@let me know How can remove  user field from checkout  for some specific category,please

Comment: Shrikant Yadav@You There Shrikant